# water pooling in concrete slab

Tags: concrete, drainage, backyard

We recently had our concrete patio and driveway completed. We have direct the water flow to the grass but the water drains out really slow and is pooling in the area. how do we solve the issue?
The new concrete slab level is below the grass, not sure if leveling the grass will help the issue.

Comment: Water flows down hill!